# Pay to view random URL (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, paypal, url-rewriting

I need some help with the following:

I have a website running on Wordpress. When the user hits the buy button (Paypal, stripe etc) and the payment is confirmed, I want to redirect them to a random page (1 of 10 pages).

I don't know how to resolve this, and one of my concerns is that people will be able to share the links that they are redirected to after the payment is successful. How do I prevent this from happening?

Appreciate all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems, restricting access to pages and redirecting to a random page.

For restricting access to pages, some kind of authentication is needed, such as membership software that gives them a login username/password to be able to access that page. There are many plugins available for Wordpress that will give membership access after taking a payment.

For redirecting to a random page you will likely need to write your own custom solution, and do it as a server-side PHP plugin if you don't want the random URLs you are redirecting to be visible.